# Unable to add Neo4j GORM plugin to a Grails project

Tags: grails, neo4j, grails-orm, grails-plugin

I want to use Neo4j graph database for my Grails project. I created a new Grails project (I'm using Intellij Ultimate Edition). The app runs fine. When I try to add the Neo4j dependency (compile ":neo4j:2.0.0-M02") in my BuildConfig.groovy and try to update the project I get the following errors in the console:

```
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc:jar:2.0.2 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc:jar:2.0.2 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc:jar:2.0.2 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Could not find artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc:jar:2.0.2 in grailsCentral  (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

Here is my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":neo4j:2.0.0-M02"
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

I even tried to install it with the 'grails install-plugin neo4j' command, but I get the same errors.
Some help would be nice.
**QUICK UPDATE**: If I replace the dependency 'compile ":neo4j:2.0.0-M02"' with ' compile ":neo4j:2.0.0-M01"' it works fine. So I guess it has to do with the latest version. I hope someone can provide me an explanation of why it doesn't work.

**Partially solved:** Thanks to Burt Beckwith I was finally able to make those dependencies work. However when I ran the app I got another error:

```
Error |
2015-01-02 13:25:59,826 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
Message: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
    Line | Method
->>  104 | postProcessBeanFactory in org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    262 | run                    in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                    in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

**End:** The last error had something to do with the hibernate plugin. I removed it, and left only Neo4j, and the app finally started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that it can't find dependency `org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc:jar:2.0.2` in `grailsCentral` but that's a little misleading - what this means is that it tried all of your repos listed in `BuildConfig.groovy` and couldn't find it in any, so it reports the last one it tried.

Googling for `neo4j-jdbc maven 2.0.2` leads to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-jdbc/2.0.2 which leads to http://m2.neo4j.org/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-jdbc/2.0.2/ and there is a `neo4j-jdbc-2.0.2.jar` there. So working backwards and removing the version, id, and group from that url you need to add this repo url:

```
repositories {
   ...
   mavenRepo 'http://m2.neo4j.org/releases'
}
```

And then it will resolve.

Comment: I added the repository url you suggested, and now i get a different error: **Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc:zip:2.0.2 in grailsCentral**. Now it can't find the .zip files. There is no end to it...

Comment: It worked in the end. I was able to get the dependencies. But i stumbled across another problem. Now when i try to run the app, it complains about some 'sessionFactory' bean not being defined.

Comment: March - 5 - 2015: Currently the repo URI for jar version 2.0.2 is returning "The server has not found anything matching the request URI"