# Grails Neo4j - missing "org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.api.BuildableCriteria" integration test fails

Tags: grails, plugins, neo4j, integration-testing

Just been trying the Neo4j Grails plugin and had some problems.

[Fixed the first myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27733242/160313) - it could find the `ne04j-jdbc` dependency. Added the mavenRepo http://m2.neo4j.org/releases to repositories and it fixed that.

I then created a domain class and integration test. Ran the test but it failed with warning about session etc, so I removed the `hibernate` plugin and `db-migration` plugin.

I now get an error like this

```
....Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.api.BuildableCriteria
```

So where is this class and why would it be missing?

If I add the `hibernate` plugin back in and re-run, I get an error like this. Either way my test won't work. Any Idea? I don't need the `hibernate` but I want to try and use neo4j

```
Error running forked test-app: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
```

In `BuildConfig.groovy` I have following plugin installed:

```
plugins {...
  compile ":neo4j:2.0.0-M02"
}
```

Stacktrace with `hibernate` still in the build looks like:

```
Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to test
...................................
|Running without daemon...
............................................Error 
|
Fatal error running tests: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:641)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory$getBean.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator.postProcessBeanFactory(PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator.groovy:104)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
Error |
Fatal error running tests: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
.Tests FAILED 
|
 - view reports in E:\workspace\ggts3.6.2-workspace\Neo4jTest\target\test-reports
Error |
Error running forked test-app: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:641)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory$getBean.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator.postProcessBeanFactory(PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator.groovy:104)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
Error |
Error running forked test-app: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
`

if I disable the hibernate plugin and re run the test I get this 

`
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to test
..................................
|Running without daemon...
...........................................Error 
|
Fatal error running tests: org/grails/datastore/mapping/query/api/BuildableCriteria (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/datastore/mapping/query/api/BuildableCriteria
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.createJavaMethod(OriginalClassInvoker.java:56)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetDeclaredMethods(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:151)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.api.BuildableCriteria
    ... 3 more
Error |
Fatal error running tests: org/grails/datastore/mapping/query/api/BuildableCriteria
.Tests FAILED 
|
 - view reports in E:\workspace\ggts3.6.2-workspace\Neo4jTest\target\test-reports
Error |
Error running forked test-app: org/grails/datastore/mapping/query/api/BuildableCriteria (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/datastore/mapping/query/api/BuildableCriteria
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.createJavaMethod(OriginalClassInvoker.java:56)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetDeclaredMethods(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:151)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.api.BuildableCriteria
    ... 3 more
Error |
Error running forked test-app: org/grails/datastore/mapping/query/api/BuildableCriteria
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

And my integration test looks like this:

```
package com.softwood

import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec

class PersonIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test create"() {
        given : "create a person"
        def p = new Person (firstName: "william", lastName: "woodman", dateOfBirth : new Date())

        when: "save him"
        p.neo4j.save (failOnError : true)

        then: 
        p.id
        def res = Person.neo4j.get(p.id)
        res.firstName == "william"
    }
}
```

Comment: That class is not introduced until Grails 3. What version of Grails are you using?

Comment: i was using grails 2.4.4  but installed the plugin as per plugins page i just created a new grails project in GGTS and installed the plugin and tried to run it

Comment: mavenRepo "http://m2.neo4j.org/releases"  //have to add to get neo4j-jdbc dependency

Comment: above is the repository i had to add to get the plgin to resolve dependencies correctly

Comment: Can you post more of the stack trace (if it exists)

Comment: not sure how to add attachment - the stack trace is too big for comment

Comment: i'll try and add to the main thread see if that works

Comment: mlan - not sure if you have seen the extra details I provided

Comment: I have. I haven't responded because I still can't tell where this might be coming from. I can say with certainty that it isn't coming from the Neo4J plugin that you are using, so you need to check for anywhere that it might be referenced, whether it is your own code or another plugin.